# Find factor pairs of an integer in Rust

Tags: performance, rust, primes, mathematics, factors

I'm trying to efficiently generate all pairs of factors of a number n.

For example, when n=27, the factor pairs are (1, 27), (3, 9), (9, 3), (27, 1)

The order in which the pairs are found is not important for my use case.

I've put together a solution using the crates `primal` and `itertools`:

- The prime sieve yields the prime factorisation of n in (prime, exponent) tuples (e.g. for n=900: (2, 2), (3, 2), (5, 2) )
- Using the cartesian product of iterators over prime^0..prime^exponent, finding all divisors d by calculating the product of each Vec, and pairing them with n/d.

This is the code I have now:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

use itertools::Itertools;

const LIMIT: usize = 50_000_000;

lazy_static! {
    static ref SIEVE: primal::Sieve = primal::Sieve::new(LIMIT);
}

fn main() {
    for n in 2..LIMIT {
        for (d1, d2) in SIEVE
            .factor(n)
            .unwrap()
            .into_iter()
            .map(|(base, exp)| (0..=(exp as u32)).map(move |e| base.pow(e)))
            .multi_cartesian_product()
            .map(|v| {
                let d = v.into_iter().product::<usize>();
                (d, n / d)
            })
        {
            println!("({d1}, {d2})");
        }
    }
}
```

It works, and it's much faster than the most naïve approach, but it's still a lot slower than I would like.

Can anyone suggest either improvements to my code or a different approach that runs significantly faster?

Comment: Is the loop of `n` from 2 to `LIMIT` just for a benchmark? If you wanted to do that for real, then that structure can be exploited to save some redundant work.

Comment: Assign `d = max(d1, d2)`. As soon as `d * d > n` you can stop. It's impossible for one of `n`'s factors to exceed `sqrt(n)`.

Comment: Not strictly true, @J_H - about half of factors are greater than `√n`, including `n` itself.  But they can all be found by considering the smaller factors, e.g. by producing `{d1, d2}` and `{d2, d1}` together, except when they are equal (`d1 == d2 == √n`).

Comment: The biggest change you can do is remove the `println`. This suggest that you should rethink your benchmarking strategy.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I'm using the println just as a placeholder for the logic that actually goes there, and I do actually need to go up to 50m.
@harold good point, I've actually managed to eliminate a few cases that don't need to be checked :)
TobySpeight that could work in theory, but unfortunately the multi_cartesian_product combinator does not yield them in ascending order. If I had another way to generate them in order, that might help, but it then also requires another .flatten() when yielding 2 tuples on each iteration.

Comment: Well, if you could limit the width to `u32` instead of `usize`, a `CONST` list of all prime numbers up to 65,536 is easy to include at zero runtime cost. However, the sieve probably doesn’t take a huge amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

My solution with a custom iterator runs almost **2x faster**. Your main bottleneck is the `multi_cartesian_product` iterator that produces results on the heap (`Vec<usize>`). There is no inherent need for getting the factors through the heap.

Speedup for LIMIT=500_000:

```
test tests::bench_factors  ... bench: 250,582,325 ns/iter (+/- 1,694,499)
test tests::bench_factors2 ... bench: 445,134,232 ns/iter (+/- 2,520,121)
```

Solution with the custom `CombineProducts`:

```rust
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;

#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

use itertools::Itertools;

const LIMIT: usize = 500_000;

lazy_static! {
    static ref SIEVE: primal::Sieve = primal::Sieve::new(LIMIT);
}

struct CombineProducts {
    factors: Vec<Factor>,
    current_product: usize,
    exhausted: bool,
}

struct Factor {
    base: usize,
    exp: usize,
    current_exp: usize,
}

impl CombineProducts {
    fn new(factors: Vec<(usize, usize)>) -> CombineProducts {
        CombineProducts {
            factors: factors.into_iter().map(|(base, exp)| Factor { base, exp, current_exp: 0, }).collect(),
            current_product: 1,
            exhausted: false,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for CombineProducts {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.exhausted {
            return None;
        }
        let result = self.current_product;
        for factor in &mut self.factors {
            if factor.current_exp == factor.exp {
                factor.current_exp = 0;
                self.current_product /= factor.base.pow(factor.exp as u32);
            } else {
                factor.current_exp += 1;
                self.current_product *= factor.base;
                return Some(result);
            }
        }
        self.exhausted = true;
        Some(result)
    }
}

fn run() -> Vec<(usize, usize)> {
    let mut result = vec![];
    for n in 2..LIMIT {
        result.extend(
            CombineProducts::new(
                SIEVE
                    .factor(n)
                    .unwrap()
            ).map(|d| (d, n / d))
        );
    }
    result
}

fn run_print() -> Vec<(usize, usize)> {
    let mut result = vec![];
    for n in 2..LIMIT {
        result.extend(
            CombineProducts::new(
                SIEVE
                    .factor(n)
                    .unwrap()
            ).map(|d| (d, n / d))
        );
    }
    println!("{:?}", result.len());
    result
}

fn run2() -> Vec<(usize, usize)> {
    let mut result = vec![];
    for n in 2..LIMIT {
        result.extend(
            SIEVE
                .factor(n)
                .unwrap()
                .into_iter()
                .map(|(base, exp)| (0..=(exp as u32)).map(move |e| base.pow(e)))
                .multi_cartesian_product()
                .map(|v| {
                    let d = v.into_iter().product::<usize>();
                    (d, n / d)
                })
        );
    }
    result
}

fn run2_print() -> Vec<(usize, usize)> {
    let mut result = vec![];
    for n in 2..LIMIT {
        result.extend(
            SIEVE
                .factor(n)
                .unwrap()
                .into_iter()
                .map(|(base, exp)| (0..=(exp as u32)).map(move |e| base.pow(e)))
                .multi_cartesian_product()
                .map(|v| {
                    let d = v.into_iter().product::<usize>();
                    (d, n / d)
                })
        );
    }
    println!("{:?}", result.len());
    result
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use test::bench::Bencher;

    #[test]
    fn test_run() {
        run_print();
    }
    #[test]
    fn test_run2() {
        run2_print();
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_factors(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            run()
        });
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_factors2(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            run2()
        });
    }
}
```